# Firefox SVG: Clip

Tags: firefox, svg

I'm trying to delete the corners of an img element:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<body>
 <style type="text/css">
 #div { background: #ffffff; width: 500px; height: 300px; padding: 10px; }
 #div img { background: #000000; }
 </style>

 <div id="div"><img src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40.714728,-73.998672&zoom=14&size=500x300&sensor=false" alt="" class="t" /></div>

 <style>.t { clip-path: url(#c1); }</style>
 <svg:svg height="0">
   <svg:clipPath id="c1" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
     <svg:polyline x="0" y="0" width="0.5" height="0.5" points="0,60 20,20 40, 100, 60,40, 80,100, 100,40 120,100" fill="red" stroke="black" />
   </svg:clipPath>
 </svg:svg>

</body>
</html>
```

But the image disapears?!

I wanted that the red marked areas will be "removed"/disapear and I don't get it work:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure your document is served as XHTML, not HTML. SVG clipping won't work otherwise. Fix your URL to use `&amp;` instead of `&`.

Then, remove the `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"` or you won't get absolute coordinates. Finally, fix your path by using the following points which should get the shape you need: `0,20 125,0 250,20 375,0 500,20 500,300 0,300`.

The final document will look like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<body>
 <style type="text/css">
 #div { background: #ffffff; width: 500px; height: 300px; padding: 10px; }
 #div img { background: #000000; }
 </style>

 <div id="div"><img src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40.714728,-73.998672&amp;zoom=14&amp;size=500x300&amp;sensor=false" alt="" class="t" /></div>

 <style>.t { clip-path: url(#c1); }</style>
 <svg:svg height="0">
   <svg:clipPath id="c1">
     <svg:polyline points="0,20 125,0 250,20 375,0 500,20 500,300 0,300" />
   </svg:clipPath>
 </svg:svg>

</body>
</html>
```